# Swift compile error - Could not build Objective-C module 'RxAlamofire'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, rxalamofire

I am using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1 And while importing  RxAlamofire to my project I am getting an error "Could not build Objective-C module 'RxAlamofire' ".

I have tried to clean the build folder and build it again. And also delete the Derived data folder and build again. But still getting the same error. Any help appreciated.
[Here is a screenshot of the error I'm getting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEqKm.png)

Podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'RiderUser' do
pod "FlagPhoneNumber"
pod "KeychainAccess"
pod "SwiftyJSON"
pod "RxAlamofire"
pod "RxSwift"
end
```